# Delta Query Limits / Limitations on Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Other Microsoft Graph features (eg Batch's limitation to five requests, or Webhook's subscription renewal) got me thinking whether there is something similar for delta query (DQ).

Is there a limit to the number of delta queries that are "active"? Eg 200 delta queries to various users' contacts - is that ok, too much, or actually no limits at all?

Do DQs need to be renewed like Webhook subscriptions? Or will be they be around "forever"? (If they eventually are purged, how would I find out about that?)

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit in my experience using the Delta Query. I have queries over 120,000 objects before.

I have not seen any documentation that shows the DQ Tokens expire. But if that is a true fear, make sure you run the request again and save the delta token returned semi-frequently? Say weekly on some sort of timer job?